# LWC: detect last element in for:each iteration

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, iteration

I'm trying to output a list of strings separated by commas in LWC, such as:

> cat, dog, mouse

I need to use template for:each and output a list item and a comma, but only if the item is not the last in the list. But I'm having trouble since LWC does not support comparison operations in templates. I tried to set a field in JS to indicate which element is the last:

HTML:

```
<template for:each={animals.data} for:item="animal">
    <b key={animal.Id}>{animal.Name}</b>
    <template if:false={animal.isLast}>
        ,&nbsp;
    </template>
</template>
```

JS:

```
@wire(getAnimals)
assignAnimals(animals) {
    this.animals = animals;
    if (this.animals.data && this.animals.data.length > 0) {
        this.animals.data[this.animals.data.length - 1].isLast = true;
    }
}
```

But I cannot assign to this.animals.data[this.animals.data.length - 1].isLast because JS Proxy is guarding it.

```
TypeError: "proxy set handler returned false for property '"isLast"'"
```

The other options would be to create isLast field in the controller, but I would need to create a wrapper class.
Another possibility would be some CSS tricks, but I don't want to do that.

Is there any simple way to do this?

Comment: the "proxy" you get is immutable, you can however, create a new array based on the proxy and then do a Join by ',' to output your desired string.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just as addition to gNerbs answer:

if you really need or want a own component you can use the iterator directive which has a first / last item attribute

Like:

```
<template>
    <template iterator:it={animals}>
        <c-child key={it.value.key} animal={it.value.value} is-last={it.last}></c-child>
    </template>
</template>
```

Full Example for your Reference: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/qaI8LcEzj/1/edit

Link to Docs: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/create_lists

Answer (score 4):

Build your string in Javascript and just display it to the page as opposed to using the `for:each` template.

```
@track animalString;

@wire(getAnimals)
assignAnimals(animals) {
    this.animals = animals;

    this.animalString = this.animals.join(', ');
}
```

Then:

```
<span>{!animalString}</span>
```

Or what ever element/component you want to use to display your string.

Comment: `this.animalString = this.animals.join(', ');`

Comment: Nice! But it only works if I actually need to output a string - which I indeed do in this case. But what if I wanted to, for example, create a child component in an iteration and pass "isLast" as a parameter to this component? I wonder if there is some more general solution. But your solution works for my case this time, thanks again :)

Comment: @Renji-xD I think your answer is probably exactly what OP is looking for. You should past it as a separate answer as I'm sure it will be accepted.

Comment: ok i added it - just don`t wanted to hijack your answer which is still valid of course ;)